# can a Sass import file path case sensitiveness cause an issue?

Tags: css, jenkins, sass

My file path is

```
@import "../../routes/uploadFile/steps/steps";
```

and folder name name is **uploadfile**.. It **not** *causing* problem locally.

But when we try to make a live build using **Jenkins** it's failing.

getting below error:-

> Error in plugin 'sass'
>   Message:
>       src/client/assets/scss/main.scss
>   Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../routes/uploadFile/steps/steps.
>          Parent style sheet: /tmp/workspace/tation-manager-client_PR-26-U53G5NXX5DKPVWWFU7OB6DVHSHHJZXT35RSBNIYVNEGHXGGJCHRA/src/client/assets/scss/main.scss
>           on line 4 of src/client/assets/scss/main.scss
>
> > @import "../../routes/uploadFile/steps/steps";
> >        ^

Comment: might be a permission issue. Please check

Comment: is working now. Issue was due to:-  uploadFile
'F' should be smaller. It behaves case sensitive while deploying for live
Thanks for responding :)

Comment: good to know. Happy coding