# Can I ignore unhandledRejection warning of node JS while deployment with CI Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am getting below warning message while building my react js project using CI

npm build fails with below message:

npm run build command contains --trace-warnings. But it has not trace exact location of warning.

> (node:179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Failed to compile server
> at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning (internal/process/promises.js:170:15)
> at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:247:11)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32) (node:179)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:179) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.
> at emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:180:11)
> at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:249:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)

Is there a way I can ignore the warning during this process as I cannot find out the cause of this warning and not able to fix this.

Node version 10.16.3

npm version. 6.9.0

Using Jenkins for CI.

Comment: This warning shouldn’t be ignored as it means that you have uncaught promises in your code base. This means that some async code is causing a rejection and it’s not being handled which could crash your app. Most common causes for this warning is when an API request is being made and you’re not handling the rejection. On that note, Node 10 is end of life and no longer supported. Highly recommend updating to Node v12+.

Comment: I understand that it should not be ignored. but I am unable to find the cause of this in my environment. So wanted to check if this can be ignored. Also if this is the problem then why it is not causing any issue in my local environment where I am using the same node and npm versions?

Comment: @MattCarlotta, Thanks for the insight.
Can you suggest how I can catch this error on the server?
I have used process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Unhandled rejection at ', promise, `reason: ${reason}`);
  process.exit(1);
});

but it didn't catch the problem. I am unable to reproduce it on my system with the same docker image and versions.

Comment: In this case, I’d recommend sharing a GitHub repo. Too hard to recommend anything without seeing the code base.

Comment: If you can’t share, then use this [error boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891261/7376526). Wrap your entire app with it, then add a `console.log(error.reason)` within the `promiseRejectionHandler` callback function.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Finally,  found the error which was leading to promise rejection. We are using webpack compiler to compile the code. It returns an error, just we missed the logs. The error was the .scss filename was not spelled case-sensitively. this works fine on local environment but gives an error on Jenkins. This error was failing the promise and promise rejection was not handled properly. We solved the error which was causing the rejection.

something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399462/can-a-sass-import-file-path-case-sensitiveness-cause-an-issue. Thanks for guiding.